# Creating a promise from multiple asynchronous file reads in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If we have:

```
fn1() {
   [filepath1, filepath2, ..., filepathN].forEach(process);

   function process(path) {
       fs.readFile(file, translate);
   }
}
```

The `translate` callback is something that operates on the contents of each file.

How do we make this return a promise such that we can do`fn1().then(fn2)`?

If there's a good solution using `async await` that would be great too.

### Assumptions

- `fn2()` needs to wait until all the file paths in the array used by `fn1` have been processed.
- `fn1()` will probably return before all the files have been processes, since fs.readFile() is asynchronous...IIUC?
  `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `await` inside a `for..of` loop:

```
async fn1() {
  for (path of [filepath1, filepath2, ..., filepathN]) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
        translate(err, data);
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

`fn1`, being an async function, will automatically return a Promise that resolves once all iterations are finished, so you could use `fn1().then(fn2)`.

If you want to `readFile` in parallel rather than serially, then better to `map` each `readFile` call into an array of promises and then use `Promise.all`:

```
fn1() {
  const arr = [filepath1, filepath2, ..., filepathN];
  return Promise.all(arr.map(path => new Promise((resolve) => {
    fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
      translate(err, data);
      resolve();
    });
  })));
}
```

Comment: this guy is crazy geek :)